# Localization of fields in the object i18n

Tags: vue.js, internationalization

I am trying to do localization with i18n and vue.
I have an object from which I print the field names.
How do I localize the names of these fields in the object itself? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
export const i18n = new VueI18n({
locale: 'en',
fallbackLocale: 'ru',
messages: {
    en: {
        nameTxt: 'Name',
        phoneTxt: 'Phone',
        emailTxt: 'Email',
        someField1Txt: 'Some Field 1',
        someField2Txt: 'Some Field 2',
    },
    ru: {
        nameTxt: 'Имя',
        phoneTxt: 'Телефон',
        emailTxt: 'Электронный адрес',
        someField1Txt: 'Дополнительное поле 1',
        someField2Txt: 'Дополнительное поле 2',
        }
    }
})

data() {
    return {
        info: [
            {
                name: this.$t('nameTxt'),
                value: '',
                pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/
            },
            {
                name: this.$t('phoneTxt'),
                value: '',
                pattern: /^[0-9]{7,14}$/
            },
            {
                name: this.$t('emailTxt'),
                value: '',
                pattern: /.+/
            },
            {
                name: this.$t('someField1Txt'),
                value: '',
                pattern: /.+/
            },
            {
                name: this.$t('someField2Txt'),
                value: '',
                pattern: /.+/
            }
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import i18n from 'VueI18n instance file'
...

data() {
    return {
        info: [
            {
                name: i18n.t('nameTxt'),
                value: '',
                pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/
            },
...
```

Just use the `t` method of the `i18n` instance.

Comment: I get an error ''ReferenceError: i18n is not defined"

Comment: try `import {i18n} from 'your export file' `

Comment: I globally import i18n in main.js. And isn't this.$t('nameTxt') the same as what you suggest?

Comment: @Tim use `computed` instead `data` and then you can access `this`